# xcode compile flags to create two apps

Tags: ios, compilation

To what extent can I use compile flags. I want to use the same xcode project but compile two apps. The differences are:

- The bundleID
- The Provisioning Profile used
- The URL that the code uses to access it's services
- The app name (the test app has 'Test' appended to it)

Comment: Create a new target in your xcode proj. 

http://samwize.com/2014/05/22/create-multiple-targets-slash-apps-for-1-xcode-project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you need two targets.  Each target get it's own bundle id, `Info.plist` etc.  Crucially, it can share source code between the two app targets, so you can create a lite and pro version of your app (not sure if that's what you are trying to do).

All you need to do is pass `-DPROVERSION=1` (or whatever) to the compiler in order to do conditional compilation within a shared source file:

```
#if PROVERSION
    // Show supadupa feature
#endif
```

This is done within the *Build Settings* of the *pro* app target.